# compare column value pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns which I create like this:

```
df_o['a'] = (df['sell'] == 1).resample(interval).sum().astype(int)
df_o['b'] = (df['sell'] == 0).resample(interval).sum().astype(int)
```

I wish to calculate ratio between those two columns, ie:

```
df_o['ratioab'] = df_o['a'] / df_o['b']
```

This works, but I can't find a way to avoid `x/0` or `0/x` which for pandas equals Inf. I this case I wish to set `df_o['ratioab'] = 0`

This doesn't work:

```
if (0 == df_o['a']).all() | (0 == df_o['b']).all():
    df_ohlc['ratioab'] = 0
```

Comment: Is possible create some sample data? Because it seems there is always `x/0` and `0/x`

Comment: Will do, but can't right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is:

```
df_o['ratioab'] = (df_o['a'] / df_o['b']).replace(np.inf, 0)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! It still bothers me that I don't know how to compare column data with python type tho.

Comment: @krizajb - I try find some sample data, but failed ;)

Comment: @krizajb - If want comapre column `a` then better is `df_o['a'] == 0`, but your code working too.

Comment: Your code has issues when used with `or` operator i.e. `df_o['a'] == 0 or (|) df_o['b'] == 0`

Comment: @krizajb - Do you think `mask = (df_o[['a','b']] == 0).all(axis=1)` and then `df_o['col'] = np.where(mask, 0, df_o['col'])` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178139/discussion-between-krizajb-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
df_o[df_o['ratioab'] == np.inf] = 0
```